# Python append method adds object to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, append

I have the following code, which is a very simplified version:

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_position(self, a):

        x, y = self.x, self.y

        x = x + a
        y = y + a

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        return self.x, self.y

    def save_position(x, y):

        coord = x, y
        positions = list(coord)

        print("The list 'positions' contains {0}".format(positions))



robot = Robot(1, 2)

coord = robot.set_position(1)
robot.save_position(coord)
```

The result is:

```
The list 'positions' contains [<__main__.Robot object at 0x02BE5490>, (2, 3)]
```

I don't get why is the object appended to the list? I would need only to make the coordinates `(2,3)` appended, giving the following result:

```
The list 'positions' contains [(2, 3)]
```

Thanks for help!

---

**EDIT : corrections based on comments**

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_position(self, a):

        x, y = self.x, self.y

        self.x += a
        self.y += a

        return self.x, self.y

    def save_position(self, coord):

        x, y = coord
        positions = list()
        positions.append(coord)

        print("The list 'positions' contains {0}".format(positions))



robot = Robot(1, 2)

coord = robot.set_position(1)
robot.save_position(coord)
```

Comment: you forgot to add `self` in `def save_position(self, x, y):`. in your implementation `x` will resolve to the current instance.

Comment: you're forgetting `self`: def save_position(x, y): and your parameter is an object, not coordinates.

Comment: why are you making copies of `self.x` and `self.y` when you're setting the position? why not `self.x += a` directly?

Comment: you also need to unpack `coord`... `robot.save_position(*coord)`. Or you could simoply change `def save_position(x, y)` to `def save_position(self, coord)` and get rid or the `coord = x, y`

Comment: @Farhan.K no, `coord` is a `Robot` object, unpacking won't do any good.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `coord` is a tuple that was returned from `set_position`

Comment: Thanks to all! I edited the post with a corrected version which is doing the job now.

Comment: `def save_position(self, *coord):` should be `def save_position(self, coord):`

Comment: @Farhan.K you're right. code is so confusing.

Comment: @Farhan.K, if I remove * in `def save_position(self, coord)`, I get: TypeError: save_position() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

Comment: sorry i said in my previous comment you can do `robot.save_position(*coord)`, OR you can change `def save_position(x, y)` to `def save_position(self, coord)` and leave `robot.save_position(coord)` as it is. You seem to have done both :)

Comment: OK thanks, it's clear!! Could anyone post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following changes:

```
    def set_position(self, a):
        coord=(self.x+a), (self.y+a)
        return (coord)
    def save_position(x, y):
        print("The list 'positions' contains {0}".format(coord))
```

it brings:

The list 'positions' contains (2, 3)

Comment: Thanks @apet for your answer.